# how many ways can a cricket team of $11$ members be selected from $15$ players given the following conditions?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can a cricket team of $11$ members be selected from $15$ players,so that a particular player is included and another player is left out?

**MyApproach**

A Particular player is included:$14$C$10$

And another player is left out:$14$C$9$

So,I get $14$C$9$=$14$C$5$

$14$ . $13$ . $12$ . $11$ . $10$/$5$ . $4$ . $3$ . $2$ =$2002$

> Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: $\binom{13}{10}$

Comment: @barakmanos Why?

Comment: @justintakro See my answer

Comment: Put those $2$ players aside for a minute. Choose $10$ out of the remaining $13$ players. Add that player who has to be included (the one that I told you to put aside)..

Comment: @barakmanos I think Choose 9 out of remaining?

Comment: That will give you $10$ players. You want to choose $11$.

Comment: @barakmanos If I place $2$ players aside for a minute(as 15-2C11-2.I would be selecting $9$ from $13$.(How I will be  selecting 10 from 13?). Given 1 player to be included  I will be  selecting 13 from 10.

Comment: "How will I be selecting $10$ from $13$"????? Just do it, nobody's stopping you!!!!!

Comment: @barakmanos haha Ya,you are right.It should be selecting 10 from 13.But I asked you my concept.Is it right?

Comment: The "particular player is included" part is right. The "another player is left out" part is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Let the person A be the particular player to be included and let person B be the particular person to be left out. Then A must be in the team and B cannot even be considered being picked, so it suffices to pick the 10 remaining players from 13 total (A is already in the team and B cannot be picked). Thus there are $\binom{13}{3} = \binom{13}{10}$ ways to pick the team.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 13C10 as we have to select only 10 members as 1 particular member is always rejected and we have to select 10 from 13 and not 15 as 1 player is never selected and one is always selected hence the answer is 286.